# How to read from Azure Event Hub in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, azure-eventhub, spring-camel

I am trying to create a route in Apache Camel that will read data from Azure Event Hub. I have tried searching all over but couldnt find a way. 
Traditional way as explained in this works, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-receive-eph

But how do I implement the same in Camel. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Some thoughts: You can use the Java code in the tutorial to create a camel component and then use that. Or maybe use it as a bean. I am currently travelling so if I get a chance I will look into this when I am on terra firma agai.

Comment: See this link: https://gaogang.wordpress.com/2017/07/30/azure-service-bus-and-apache-camel/ this should be somewhere to start.